# Probabilities of errors in three independent transmissions

Tags: probability-distributions

i have been working through some old exam papers and have gotten stuck on this last one. can anyone help?

When a piece of information (a bit) is transmitted over a communications channel, it may be wrongly communicated. One method of improving reliability is to transmit the same piece of information an odd number of times, and use a majority decoder. The information is taken to be the bit received the most (from the odd number). A simple model for noisy communication is to assume that each transmitted bit is independently corrupted during transmission with the same probability $p$ where $0 < p < 1$. Now consider a two-out-of-three majority decoder.

(a) Let $Y$ be the random variable that counts how many (out of the three bits) are correctly communicated. What are the possible values of $Y$ ?

(b) Find the probability mass function of $Y$ , writing it either in a table or as a list.

(c) For which values of $Y$ will the majority decoder correctly interpret the information sent?

(d) In terms of $p$, what is the probability that a piece of information is correctly communicated? Also write this in terms of $F(y)$.

(e) For what values of $p$ is the majority decoder more reliable than transmitting the message only once?

i am assuming the answer to (a) is $Y=0,1,2,3$ but my answers for the rest are not making sense

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(a) You are correct, $Y$ can be either $0,1,2$ or $3$.

(b) You simply need to calculate $P(Y=0), P(Y=1), P(Y=2)$ and $P(Y=3)$. How would you calculate $P(Y=0)$? Remember, $P(Y=0)$ is the probability that no errors occured, which means that it is the probability that no error occured in the first transmission **and** no error occured in the second transmission **and** no error occured in the third transmission.

(c) Is the decoder correct if $Y=0$? What about if $Y=1$? If $Y=2$? What about $Y=3$?

(d) After you answer (c), this answer will be easier.

(e) After you answer (d), this answer will be easier.

Comment: how do i calculate P(Y=0), P(Y=1), etc with what i have been given? that's whats really got me?

Comment: @Rachael Did you read the part where I said that $P(Y=0)$ is the probability of (something **and** something else **and** something else)? Do you remember how you calculate $P(A\text{ and } B$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent?